# Loading images on web-sites

Tags: javascript, image, caching, image-uploading

Help me please with understanding process of images loading on site. For example: I create img elements using code:

```
img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'some image src';
someDiv.appendChild(img);
```

Is it right, that every time this script works, user's browser downloades image? And what about not the first loading of image? What if script works twice with the same image src?

Also, the same question in simple html-code:

```
<img src='somesrc' /><img src='thesamesrc' />
```

Does the browser load this image twice?

So, the main question is: If browser loads images every time with my javascript-code, how to fix it? I have some set of images and I need to load one of them with some interval. How to load all of them at once and use it after that? Of course, if browser caches images in this case, there is no question, but I'm not sure

Comment: The image will only be downloaded if it's not already cached. So if you use the same image twice in a website, the image will only need to be loaded once.

Comment: So tempting to make an answer with "No."

Comment: Thank you very much, and will caching also work if I remove image with javascript and then load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image will only load once if caching is enabled. There are expiration dates when files will be reloaded.

Check out https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching for more information on caching.